# Correlation of a matrix vs Conditional probability of a matrix

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, text-mining, linear-algebra

I am confused how to justify that why eigenvalues of correlation matrix of a document-term matrix (dtm) is different from the eigenvalues of matrix of conditional probability between the terms?
In fact, I would like to know what the difference between correlation and conditional probability represent in terms of the eigenvalues in such data?

More details about the algorithm:

```
Input = Document-term matrix(dtm)
1- co.dtm = compute correlation of dtm
2- coEig = compute eigenvalues of co.dtm
3- pro.dtm = compute conditional probability of dtm
4- proEig = compute eigenvalues of pro.dtm
```

What the difference between coEig and proEig tells us? And what we can infer from each of them?

Comment: Could you please tell us what the "conditional probability matrix" of a set of data is?

Comment: @whuber I updated the question.